# Converting this cURL for Guzzle

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest, guzzle

I've tried reading through the Guzzle docs but I can't wrap my head around this problem.

I want to use Guzzle instead of cURL for the following:

```
protected $url = 'https://secure.abcdef.com/cgi/xml_request_server.php';

    $xml =  "<ABCRequest>\n";
    $xml .=     "<Authentication>\n";
    $xml .=         "<ABLogin>$this->gwlogin</ABLogin>\n";
    $xml .=         "<ABKey>$this->gwkey</ABKey>\n";
    $xml .=     "</Authentication>\n";
    $xml .=     "<Request>\n";
    $xml .=            "<RequestType>SearchABC</RequestType>\n";
    $xml .=        "</Request>\n";
    $xml .= "</ABCRequest>\n";

    $header =  "POST $this->url HTTP/1.1\n";
    $header .= "Host: domain.com\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml)."\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF8\n";
    $header .= "Connection: close; Keep-Alive\n\n";
    $header .= $xml;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I tried this but I'm still new at this...:

```
$client = new Client($this->url);
$response = $client->get($xml);
```

Comment: In addition to the answer you've got already you might find it useful to learn about HEREDOC type of strings in PHP: http://php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make use of the [`Client::post()` magic method](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#sending-requests) to create a HTTP POST request:

```
$client = new Client($this->url);
$request = $client->post(
    '', 
    ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'], 
    $xml, 
    ['timeout' => 120]
);
$response = $request->send()->xml();;
```

Comment: Perfect. I modified it slightly to get the xml: $request = $this->client->post('', array(), $xml);
  $response = $request->send()->xml();

Comment: I do not think this example covers the timeout setting of 120 seconds and it does not address the content-type and charset-encoding use within the request body.

Comment: @hakre try updated one, and read docs - http://guzzlephp.org/http-client/client.html#creating-requests-with-a-client here are samples