# Sending Media Files using CURL - Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am posting data(including a media file (.wav)) from my app to an API with curl. When submitting my data, i check for the data including the mediafile submitted in my API. From the response i get from my API, see below

**Response**

```
  {"status":"success","media":false,"data":{"message":"Media Campaign","recipient":["34505140704"],
"file":{"name":"\/Users\/path\/to\/folder\/public\/Voice\/aaaah.wav","mime":null,"postname":null}}}true
```

In the response, the file is being retrieved as well but when i check for the file using **$request->hasFile('file') or $request->file('file')**, I get `false` and `null` respectively.

Can someone let me know why this is happening in my code please ?

**Controller**

```
public function test()
{
   $file_name_with_full_path = '/Users/path/to/folder/public/Voice/aaaah.wav';
    if(function_exists('curl_file_create'))
    {
      $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
    }
    else
    {
      $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);  
    }
    $post = array('message' => 'Media Campaign', 'recipient' => ['34505140704'],'file' => $cFile);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

**APIController**

```
public function campaign(Request $request)

{
     if (($request->get('message')) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'data' => $request->all()
            ]);
        }

}
```

Comment: `$request->hasFile('file')` checks if the request has an uploaded file. You appear to be sending a file *path*, which isn't the same thing - it's just a string, not a file.

Comment: @ceejayoz, okay. i am basically trying to get the file uploaded. How do i achieve that ?

Comment: See [https://php.net/curl_file_create](http://php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php)

Comment: @ceejayoz, how different is my code from the link you just sent ? Did you take a look at it ?

Comment: You've got a `function_exists('curl_file_create')` check. Are you sure it exists on your PHP version?

Comment: I am using php version 7 @ceejayoz

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'd use Guzzle to hide the details of cURL requests in PHP. The way PHP's cURL extension handles file transfers changed a couple of years ago, which broke a lot of legacy code at the company I was working for. By using a third-party wrapper like Guzzle, you can let the Guzzle developers worry about changes in the underlying extension - all you need to do is keep your Guzzle package up to date.

[PHP - Why Use Guzzle Instead of cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548005/php-why-use-guzzle-instead-of-curl#36549547)